# I am not getting full results in 2019 SSMS, it is truncated, I want to display 2729 characters

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I am displaying `FORMATEMESSAGE` in SSMS 2019 and it ends with Ellipsis '...'.

I tried `PRINT(@var)` and it is displaying full message, but with `CONCAT` or `FORMATEMESSAGE` it ends with `'...'` only after 1000 characters. My full length is 2729. I know that `FORMATEMESSAGE` contains only 2047 characters, but what is the alternative for it if I need the result `'EXEC this and that'` ?

Comment: How do you output your results -  `Results to grid` or `Results to text`?

Comment: I tried both ways. But I want the answer  to grid.

Comment: I can't test with SSMS 2019, but in SSMS 2012 the maximum characters in each column for `Result to text` is an option in `Options\Query Results`. Check these options in SSMS 2019. Thanks.

Comment: Simple `SELECT ` statement works for 2017 version, but for 2019 version doesn't, options seems to be the same, can't figure it out why.

Answer (score 1):

From [FORMATMESSAGE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/formatmessage-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> msg_string 
>   Applies to: SQL Server ( SQL Server 2016 (13.x) through
>   current version).
>
> Is a string enclosed in single quotes and containing parameter value
>   placeholders. The error message can have a maximum of 2,047
>   characters. If the message contains 2,048 or more characters, only the
>   first 2,044 are displayed and an ellipsis is added to indicate that
>   the message has been truncated. Note that substitution parameters
>   consume more characters than the output shows because of internal
>   storage behavior. For information about the structure of a message
>   string and the use of parameters in the string, see the description of
>   the msg_str argument in RAISERROR (Transact-SQL).

2729 characters is too long for `FORMATMESSAGE`.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but what should I use if I want to get result 'EXEC blablabla' ?